# Colar números sem formatação

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como eu poderia fazer para remover os pontos de um formatos de números?

Por exemplo, eu pego e copio um valor *000.000.000* e colo ele no meu `input`, ele deixaria automaticamente essa formatação dele e ficaria "*000000000*".

Achei uma máscara, só que ela não está executando aqui.

Meu input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="var_est" value="" onchange="tiraMascara(this)" placeholder="" data-size="small" mask="#000.000.000.000" data-only-numbers="" required="required" style="width: 100%;">
```

A máscara:

```
<script>
function removeMaskMoney (x){
    x = ""+x;
    y = 0;
    if ((x.replace(",", ".") != x )){
        if (x.replace(".", "") != x ){
            aux = x;
            x = x.replace(".", "");    
            x = x.replace(".", "");                            
        }
        else {
            aux = x;
        }
        if(x.replace(",", ".") != x){
            x = x.replace(",", ".")
        }else{
            x = aux;
        }
    }
    if (isNaN(parseFloat(x)) ){
        x = 0;
    }else{
        x = parseFloat(x)
    }
    return x;
}

function tiraMascara(e){
    value = removeMaskMoney ($(e).val());
    $("[name=var_est_sem_mask]").val( value)
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar [expressão regular](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) e [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) para substituir todo caractere que não seja número por `''`.

```
"000.000.000".replace(/\D+/g, '');  // "000000000"
```

O [`\D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-non-digit) faz com que a Regex case com qualquer caractere que não seja um número(`[0-9]`).

O [`+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-plus) é um quantificador que significa "uma ou mais vezes". Ou seja, ele vai casar com qualquer caractere que não seja um número que se repita 1 ou mais vezes.

E por fim, a flag [`g`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags) especifica que o replace vai ser global, ou seja, não vai parar na primeira substituição.

Um exemplo bem simples funcionando:

```js
var $input = $('#teste');
var $feedback = $('#feedback');

$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  $feedback.html($input.val().replace(/\D+/g, ''))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input id="teste"/>
<button id="btn">!!!</button>
<div id="feedback"></div>
```